Reading nested structs from PLC with S7.Net in C#
I'm using S7.Net to read data from a Siemens PLC into my C# application. I can successfully read simple data blocks, but I'm encountering problems when trying to read a data block containing nested structs.
Here's an example of a simple data block that I can read successfully:
DATA_BLOCK "Data_block_2"
{
    S7_Optimized_Access := 'FALSE'
    VERSION : 0.1
    NON_RETAIN
    STRUCT 
        Data_1 : Real;
        Data_2 : Real;
        Data_3 : String;
    END_STRUCT;
}

I read this data block in C# using the following class:
public class DB2
{
    public float Data_1 { get; set; }
    public float Data_2 { get; set; }
    [S7String(S7StringType.S7String, 254)]
    public string Data_3 { get; set; }
}

And I perform the read operation like this:
plc.ReadClass<DB2>(2);

However, I run into issues with a data block like the following, which includes nested structs:
DATA_BLOCK "Data_block_5"
{
    S7_Optimized_Access := 'FALSE'
    VERSION : 0.1
    NON_RETAIN
    STRUCT 
        data_1 : Bool;
        data_2 : Real;
        data_3 : Int;
        data_4 : Word;
        data_5 : Struct
            deneme_1 : Struct
                data_1 : Real;
                data_2 : Struct
                    sensor_1 : Bool;
                    sensorler : Struct
                        _1 : Bool;
                        _2 : Bool;
                        _3 : Bool;
                    END_STRUCT;
                END_STRUCT;
            END_STRUCT;
            deneme_2 : Real;
            deneme_3 : Bool;
        END_STRUCT;
        ddd : String[25];
    END_STRUCT;
}

My attempt to model this in C# is as follows:
public class DB6
{
    public bool data_1 { get; set; }
    public float data_2 { get; set; }
    public short data_3 { get; set; }
    public ushort data_4 { get; set; }
    public Data5 data_5 { get; set; }
    [S7String(S7StringType.S7String, 25)]
    public string ddd { get; set; }
}

public class Data5
{
    public Deneme1 deneme_1 { get; set; }
    // Other properties...
}

// Nested classes defined similarly...
When I try to read this structure using ReadClass or ReadStruct, the data is not read correctly, or I encounter errors.
How can I properly read this structure? What are the best practices for reading a PLC data block with nested structs into C# using S7.Net?

what are the errors? Are you sure there should not be any attributes on the class or property to guide deserialization?

Thank you for your response.
The main error I encounter is that the data doesn't seem to be correctly deserialized into my C# class structure. Specifically, when I try to read the nested struct data from the PLC, the resulting object in C# doesn't reflect the expected values from the PLC.

Regarding your question about attributes, I am using the [S7String] attribute for strings to guide the deserialization process, as shown in my DB2 class example. However, for the nested structures in DB6, I am not sure which attributes should be used to ensure proper deserialization, especially considering the nested structs.
Do I need to use specific attributes for nested structs or is there a different approach I should take to handle the deserialization of such complex data structures from the PLC?

Other serialization libraries often use attributes. But I have no idea about S7, I have never used it. The documentation should ideally have a section about complex types should be handled.

Indeed, the documentation for the S7.Net library primarily discusses handling of simple data types and basic read/write operations. I've noticed that it lacks detailed information on dealing with more complex types, especially nested structures like the ones I am dealing with. This has made it challenging to understand how to properly implement deserialization for these complex nested types in the PLC data blocks.

Look at public Data5 data_5. Your Data5 type is declared as a class, so that data_5 is going to be a 4-byte quantity (well on 32 bit, 8 bytes on 64 bit). Ditch the classes and move to structs. While you are at it, ditch the properties and use fields (you can still create properties that reference the fields if you like). Prevent the compiler from rearranging things by using [StructLayout] attributes on the fields. N9te that I have no experience with Siemens interop, so i.may be completely wrong.

did you solver your issue?, the serialization approach is very complicated, in my experience the best way is to read bulk data (byte stream) byte[] after that parse them using the data type length, i would invest time in a class or logic to determine the varaible offset to the first variable(that is not as trivial as it sound)
